# C# linq query aggregate nullable boolean

Tags: c#, linq, boolean, nullable

I'd like to use linq to aggregate a nullable bool following the logic:

- If all is true then true;
- if all is false then false;
- else null

Here is my code, I couldn't get the bool aggregate.

```
class T1
{
  public string property1{get;set;}
  public string property2{get;set;}
  public bool? BoolProperty{get;set;}
}

///initialize a list<T1> t2 with values......
List<T1> t2 = new List<T1>();
t2.Add(new T1() 
        {
            property1="hello",
            property2="world",
            BoolProperty=true
        });
t2.Add(new T1() 
        {
            property1="hello",
            property2="world",
            BoolProperty=false
        });

List<T1> t1 = t2.GroupBy(g => new
        {
            g.property1,
            g.property2               
        })
        .Select(g => new T1
        {
            property1 = g.Key.property1,
            property2 = g.Key.property2,                
            BoolProperty = ////can someone help? if all object in t2 are true, true; if all object in t2 are false, false; else null
 ///in this case i am expecting a null
        }).ToList();
```

So t1 will be "hello", "world", null;
Thanks

Comment: I wish I can choose multiple answers.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your code,

```
List<T1> t1 = t2.GroupBy(g => new
        {
            g.property1,
            g.property2               
        })
        .Select(g => new T1
        {
            property1 = g.Key.property1,
            property2 = g.Key.property2,                
            BoolProperty =  g.GroupBy(grp => grp.BoolProperty).Count() > 1 ? null : g.Select(g_val=>g_val.BoolProperty).First()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
BoolProperty = g.All(p => p.BoolProperty.GetValueOrDefault())
    ? true
    : (g.All(p => !(p.BoolProperty ?? true))
        ? (bool?)false
        : null)
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: this seems to be working....but I am not sure why someone downvoted this with no comments?

Comment: Yeah not sure why it was downvoted either!  Accept if it worked for you! :)

Comment: I am waiting for that comments while do more tests

Comment: The one downside of this approach I see is that the `All` must iterate over the data set twice. Not a huge downside, admittedly.

Comment: `p.BoolProperty.HasValue && !p.BoolProperty.Value` could perhaps be simplified to `!(p.BoolProperty ?? true)` and `p.BoolProperty.HasValue && p.BoolProperty.Value` to `p.BoolProperty ?? false`.

Comment: @mjwills Updated.

Comment: One thing about this new version is that it doesn't treat null bools the same way if they are present in the input.  Not sure if that's a problem.  Here's the original if it is:
    BoolProperty = g.All(p => p.BoolProperty.HasValue && p.BoolProperty.Value)
        ? true
        : (g.All(p => p.BoolProperty.HasValue && !p.BoolProperty.Value)
            ? (bool?)false
            : null)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following solution. It requires the use of [`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).

```
List<T1> t1 = t2.GroupBy(g => new
{
    g.property1,
    g.property2
}).Select(groupedItems =>
    {
        // My code starts here
        bool? result = null;
        var bools = groupedItems
            .OrderBy(z => z.BoolProperty)
            .TagFirstLast((z, first, last) => new { z, firstOrLast = first || last })
            .Where(z => z.firstOrLast)
            .Select(z => z.z.BoolProperty).ToList();

        if (bools.Count == 0)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else if (bools.First() == bools.Last())
        {
            result = bools.First();
        }
        // My code ends here

        return new T1
        {
            property1 = groupedItems.Key.property1,
            property2 = groupedItems.Key.property2,
            BoolProperty = result
        };
    }).ToList();
```

The key bit is the use of `OrderBy`, to ensure that the `true`, `false` and `null` values are adjacent (i.e. grouped together in order).

Then `TagFirstLast` allows us to ignore everything other than the first and last entries (which is all we need).

Then we check whether the first and last entry are the same - if they are, use that value (whether it be `null` or `true` or `false` - either way it fits the requirements).

Otherwise, use `null` (since that would be your `else` condition).

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done by linq, but that would propbably never be the most efficient way because you either need to enumerate more than once or other shenenigans. Sometimes best approach ist plain old code.

```
public static bool? CantFindAgoodName(IEnumerable<bool?> items)
{ 
     bool? check = null;
     bool first = true;
     foreach(var item in items)
     {
         if(first)
         {
            check = item;
            first = false;
         }
         else if(check != item) 
            return null;
     }
     return check;
}
```

Then just write

```
BoolProperty = CantFindAGoodName(g)
```

If you really wanna do it with standard Linq, it can be done with a single iteration, but its neither efficient (because it doesnt break imediately) nor beatuiful...

```
BoolProperty = g.Aggregate(-1,
              (n, b) => n == -1
                ? (b == null ? 0 : (b.Value ? 1 : 2))
                : (n == (b == null ? 0 : (b.Value ? 1 : 2)) ? n : -2), 
              i => i == -2 ? default(bool?) : i == 1);
```

So how does it work?

```
-1  = seed
 0  = null
 1  = true
 2  = false
-2  = different values aka null
```

While the value is either the first or equals its predecessor, it keeps getting forwareded. So if the sequence consists purely of the same element, that will get forwarded. If its different however, -2 will get forwarded, which will allways be different to any other element remaining.
In the end the second lambda just transforms the result back into a `bool?`

Comment: Elegant and uses less resources. Wow, answers are just getting better

Comment: So what if the input list is null, false, false, false?  It would return False, while the expected return is null. Correct me if I am wrong....thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg You are wrong. Why dont you just test it... https://dotnetfiddle.net/1tS3sv

Comment: I was testing the function CantFindAGoodName, it returns false....https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqQpqy

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var allTrue = t2.All(x=>x.BoolProperty == true);
var allFalse = t2.All(x=>x.BoolProperty == false);
var anyNull = t2.Any(x=>x.BoolProperty.HasValue == false);
```

before grouping.